# App Store Rejection: Performance: App Completeness

Tags: ios

Disclaimer:
This app has been on the App Store for more than 3 years now and I haven't done any changes regarding Network.

Apple's review notes:

> Guideline 2.1 - Performance
>
> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad
>   running iOS 10.3.1 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.
>
> Specifically, your app displayed an error message when we tried to
>   create an account.
>
> Please see attached screenshots for details.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please run your app on a device while connected
>   to an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to identify any
>   issues, then revise and resubmit your app for review.
>
> If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to
>   this message in Resolution Center to provide information on how these
>   features were intended to work.
>
> For new apps, uninstall all previous versions of your app from a
>   device, then install and follow the steps to reproduce the issue. For
>   updates, install the new version as an update to the previous version,
>   then follow the steps to reproduce the issue.
>
> Resources
>
> For information about supporting IPv6 Networks, please review
>   Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks and About Networking.
>
> Guideline 2.1 - Information Needed
>
> We were unable to sign in to review your app with the demo account
>   information you provided.
>
> We have attached a screenshot of the error message displayed when we
>   attempted to sign in.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To help us proceed with the review of your app, please provide a user
>   name and password in the App Review Information section for your app
>   in iTunes Connect. Please be sure to include content in your app that
>   demonstrates the features and functionality available in your app.
>
> To provide demo account information:
>
> - Log in to iTunes Connect
> - Click on "My Apps"
> - Select your app
> - Click on the app version on the left side of the screen
> - Scroll down to "App Review Information"
> - Provide information in "Demo Account" and/or "Notes" as appropriate
> - Click "Done"
> - Once you've completed all changes, click the "Save" button at the top of the App Version Information page.
> - Reply to this message to confirm the availability of a valid demo account and we will continue the review.
>
> While your iTunes Connect status shows as Metadata Rejected, we do not
>   require a new binary to correct this issue. Once this information is
>   available, we can continue your review.

Could anyone help me understand what is going on?

Comment: Test your app on an IPv6 network - if everything works, simply upload it again, there have been cases where second round of review proved successful.

Comment: How can I test this in a iPv6 network? Is that a way to simulate that?

Comment: @RafaelNascimento
I Know it's too late but one can flash a iPv6 network(help of internet sharing) using a mac, please follow this apple official link and the step within it. (inside link search for "Test for IPv6")
Link: [ https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1 ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Apple began requiring all App Store submissions to support IPv6-only networks as of June 1, 2016.](https://developer.apple.com/support/ipv6/)

[Apple began reviewing existing apps on September 7, 2016](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store-improvements/) to remove “apps that no longer function as intended, don’t follow current review guidelines, or are outdated.”

The message you received indicates that Apple reviewed your app and found that it didn't work on an IPv6-only network. This means it doesn't follow current review guidelines and is eligible for removal.

You need to test your app on an IPv6-only network, figure out why it doesn't work, fix it, and submit the fixed version.

Comment: How can I test this in a iPv6 network? Is that a way to simulate that?

Comment: Read the “Testing your app in an IPv6-only environment” section of the first document I linked.